# require.js from composer installed components

Tags: composer-php, requirejs

I'm building an PHP-application, loading the dependencies with composer. Also jquery and some js-libs where loaded by composer.

```
{
    "config": {
        "secure-http": false
    },
    "require": {
        //removed the php-libs for better overview
        "moment/moment": "dev-master",
        "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "v3.4.1",
        "components/jquery": "dev-master",
        "eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

After composer install I have a directory "components" and there I can find a require.js-file.
I tried to load all the js-libs (jquery, moment, bootstrap-datetimepicker) by simply loading this require.js-file, but this did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/require.js"></script>
```

How is it done right?

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? What error do you get? Can the `/components/require.js` resource be loaded by the browser?

Comment: "does not work" means: jquery, moment and bootstrap-datetimepicker are not available. The require.js is accessible for the browser.